# Принудительно загрузить скрипт

Tags: javascript, ajax

Добрый день.
Скажите, можно ли как-то принудительно загрузить скрипт JS?
Ситуация такая:
На сайте есть плеер, работающий через Ajax. Для того, чтобы музон не перрывался при переходе по разделам сайта, переходы сделаны через ajax и меняется только контентная часть страницы, остальное остается статическим.
Но проблема в том, что если я к примеру перешел на страницу site.ru/razdel, где у меня выводится список музыки, то по клику на кнопку воспроизведения, данная музыка открывает плеер в новом окне.
Если же я просто обновлю страницу site.ru/razdel то при том же клике запускается правильный плеер без перегрузки страницы.
Выяснил что при клике запускается определенный скрипт, так вот он в исходном коде есть, но не срабатывает почему-то.

UPD:
Выручайте))
Смотрю, почему-то через ajax вообще никакого объекта нет на этой ссылке.
Вот скрин при обычной загрузке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И скрин при ajax переходах
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD4: На ссылку на клик висит такое событие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот скрин с функцией
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: очевидно, если он есть и не срабатывает, значит он не вызывается) дебажить надо

Comment: Не сталкивался. Скрипт можно "закидывать" ф-цией eval(твой_скрипт). Возможно поможет добавление в document.scripts.

Comment: Может мне скинуть ссылку на страницу, чтобы Вам было проще понять ситуацию? Я уже всю голову поломал(((

Comment: @Batyabest нахождение скрипта на странице, не означает то, что он должен работать и вызываться `сам по себе, когда захочет`. Открывайте devTools, ставьте брейкпоинты и смотрите, куда у вас заходит, а куда нет. Возможно у вас после переходов, не навешиваются события, поэтому все работает криво

Comment: @Batyabest увы у меня нет времени, я могу лишь помочь решить ваши ошибки, и подсказать варианты этих решений. Если не знаете как `дебажить` код, то почитайте об этом в интернете. Если вы уже написали часть вашего сайта, вы должны знать такие мелочи. Без этого далеко не уплывете

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, обновил вопрос. Какие можно сделать выводы из этого?

Comment: @Batyabest никаких))) Тут ничего не показывает так то)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, а на новых скинах? Почему-то при обычной загрузке есть Object, а при ajax - нет.

Comment: @Batyabest так я же говорю, на загруженные элементы у вас скрипт не действует. В самом скрипте как подписка на клик происходит? добавьте

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев? не понял что значит подписка на скрипт. Как это сделать?

Comment: ну у вас есть подписка на событие клика, код этой подписки нужен

Comment: Имеете ввиду, как вызывается данный скрипт? Я так понял этот кусок кода $(this).click(function(b) {
                b.preventDefault();
                c != a.config.diag.index ? a._setSound(c, !0) : a.togglePause()
            })
        }));

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, обновил вопрос